# Select COUNT with sub-query or separate query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using DataTables to display the data. It requires the total count of rows, So which approach is better for this case?

1- Sub-query:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE active = 1) AS total_count FROM employees e JOIN users u ON u.id = e.user_id WHERE u.active = 1
```

This would return:

```
___________________________
| id | name | total_count |
|____|______|_____________|         
| 1  | John |      7      |
| 2  | Mark |      7      |
| .. | ..   |      7      |
|____|______|_____________|
```

2- Separate query:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name FROM employees e JOIN users u ON u.id = e.user_id WHERE u.active = 1

SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE active = 1
```

This 1st query would return:

```
____________
| id | name | 
|____|______|   
| 1  | John |
| 2  | Mark |
| .. | ..   |
|____|______|
```

The 2nd one would return:

```
_____________
| COUNT(id) |
|___________|   
|     7     |  
|___________|
```

Comment: what is the requirement? what fields you want in output?

Comment: Your 1st query - it's bad in general, db will work a lot without any sense. 2nd is much better, because it's not related tasks (one query receives active users, next only their count).

Comment: @VN'sCorner Just right there in the 1st 2 lines 'So which approach is better for this case?'

Comment: @VN'sCorner I want to output the user data + the total number of users

Comment: in this case you need two queries as your 2nd example.

Answer (score 0):

If the dataset is small then the 1st query wouldn't harm.The only drawback is since inline view is part of select statement it will get executed for each record being returned by the join between `employees` and `users`.
Here is a better option from performance standpoint,the inline view represents a table and the total_count can now be part of select statement :

```
SELECT u.id, u.name,total_count.tot_count  
FROM (SELECT COUNT(id) tot_count FROM users WHERE active = 1) AS total_count,
                            employees e JOIN users u 
ON u.id = e.user_id WHERE u.active = 1;
```